# find complex numbers satisfying relation

Tags: complex-numbers

Find complex numbers satisfying relation:

$$z = \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)\bar{z}$$

Comment: do you mean $$z=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)\bar{z}$$?

Comment: Do you know the goemetric interpretation of complex numbers, and the effect of multiplication on it?

Comment: @Henrik I do not know. I'm trying to understand what's written at the end of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve the equation
$$x+iy=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)(x-iy)$$
it is equivalent to
$$0=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y+i\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}y\right)$$
now you must solve the system
$$-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y=0$$ and
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}y=0$$ for $x,y$

Comment: ok thank you corrected!

Comment: When I find x and y, is it decided?

Comment: yes then you will get the solution

Comment: should i do it for you?

Comment: Sorry, but if it's not difficult for you, then yes

Comment: the solution is given by $$y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x$$

Comment: i wish you a happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the relation as $\, z=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}3}\bar z$.

What does it imply for $\,\arg z\,$?